# Audio in html page continues to play even after I exit the web browser control windows phone 8

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8

I have a audio tag in the html page which is loaded in the web browser control in windows phone 8. When I play the audio in this page it continues to play even after I have exited the web browser control. I want to stop the playing audio once i click on the back button.

How can i achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to reload the page. I guess.. Using the following method..

var js = "window.location.reload(true);";
 wbcontent.InvokeScript("eval", js);

But what i really do want to know is why the audio continues to play even after i have exited the web browser control.